# How fix Error: The file name must end with .xml

Tags: android, kotlin

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /home/bestiger/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/Newspaper-master/app/src/main/res/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar: Error: The file name must end with .xml

[image]

Comment: Do all of your `xml` files and with `.xml`?

Comment: I checked well. SO everything is on .xml

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtQ27uO091k

Comment: Add a snippet of your project res folder structure and its files